# rfkill unable to remove soft block

Tags: drivers, bluetooth, dell, intel, atheros

`rfkill` lists my Bluetooth as soft-blocked:

```
root@zeljava:~# rfkill --output-all
ID TYPE      DEVICE TYPE-DESC         SOFT      HARD
 3 wlan      phy1   Wireless LAN unblocked unblocked
 4 bluetooth hci0   Bluetooth      blocked unblocked
```

Running `rfkill unblock all` or `rfkill unblock bluetooth` seems to be unable to turn it on:

```
root@zeljava:~# rfkill unblock bluetooth
root@zeljava:~# rfkill unblock all
root@zeljava:~# rfkill --output-all
ID TYPE      DEVICE TYPE-DESC         SOFT      HARD
 3 wlan      phy1   Wireless LAN unblocked unblocked
 4 bluetooth hci0   Bluetooth      blocked unblocked
```

I'm running Ubuntu 21.04 on a Dell Inspiron 5379 laptop. Network adapter is a Qualcomm device:

```
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [168c:003e] (rev 32)
    Subsystem: Dell QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [1028:0310]
    Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci
    Kernel modules: ath10k_pci
root@zeljava:~# lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04f3:2494 Elan Microelectronics Corp. Touchscreen
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0cf3:e007 Qualcomm Atheros Communications 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0bda:58f3 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Integrated_Webcam_HD
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
root@zeljava:~# lsusb -t
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/6p, 5000M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/12p, 480M
    |__ Port 5: Dev 2, If 3, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
    |__ Port 5: Dev 2, If 1, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
    |__ Port 5: Dev 2, If 2, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
    |__ Port 5: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
    |__ Port 7: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
    |__ Port 7: Dev 3, If 1, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
    |__ Port 8: Dev 4, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
```

I've checked the BIOS and Bluetooth is enabled. The only apparently-related messaged I could find on `dmesg` is:

```
[ 3639.167592] Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected event for opcode 0x0c03
[ 3639.169588] Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected event for opcode 0x1003
```

Kernel version:

```
root@zeljava:~# uname -a
Linux zeljava 5.11.0-37-generic #41-Ubuntu SMP Mon Sep 20 16:39:20 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Any suggestions on how I could remove this soft block?

---

EDIT:

I've ended up buying a new adapter:

```
vitor@zeljava:~$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A3
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX210/AX211/AX411 160MHz [8086:2725] (rev 1a)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX210 160MHz [8086:0024]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi

vitor@zeljava:~$ lsusb -tv
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/6p, 5000M
    ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/12p, 480M
    ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
    |__ Port 5: Dev 2, If 3, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
        ID 0bda:58f3 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
    |__ Port 5: Dev 2, If 1, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
        ID 0bda:58f3 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
    |__ Port 5: Dev 2, If 2, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
        ID 0bda:58f3 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
    |__ Port 5: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
        ID 0bda:58f3 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
    |__ Port 7: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
        ID 8087:0032 Intel Corp. 
    |__ Port 7: Dev 3, If 1, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
        ID 8087:0032 Intel Corp. 
    |__ Port 8: Dev 4, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
        ID 04f3:2494 Elan Microelectronics Corp.
```

*Absolutely* no difference. Disabled/enabled bluetooth in the BIOS settings. Tried using `connman`, setting the `Powered` property to `On` using `bluez-tools`, nothing works so far...

The only processes consuming `/dev/rfkill` is GNOME:

```
itor@zeljava:~$ fuser /dev/rfkill
/dev/rfkill:          6359
vitor@zeljava:~$ ps aux | grep 6359
vitor       6359  0.0  0.0 460376  6624 ?        Ssl  18:31   0:00 /usr/libexec/gsd-rfkill
vitor      19955  0.0  0.0  11900  2252 pts/0    S+   19:03   0:00 grep --color=auto 6359
```

Right now, I might try nuking this install and trying again.

Comment: What is the version of the kernel version as well.

Comment: @David 5.11.0-37, added to the question as well for completeness.